# Hover color always triggered on first button in jquery buttonset - how to stop it?

Tags: jquery, css, jqueryi-ui-buttonset

I have this buttonset:

```
<input type="radio" id="p1" name="pi" /><label for="p1">3</label>
<input type="radio" id="p2" name="pi" /><label for="p2">2</label>
<input type="radio" id="p3" name="pi" /><label for="p3">1</label>
<input type="radio" id="p4" name="pi" checked="checked" /><label for="p4">0</label>
<input type="radio" id="p5" name="pi" /><label for="p5">1</label>
<input type="radio" id="p6" name="pi" /><label for="p6">2</label>
<input type="radio" id="p7" name="pi" /><label for="p7">3</label>
```

and trigger the jquery buttonset styling with

```
$("#pi").buttonset();
```

It works fine, only the p1 button always starts out highlighted with the hover color.

As soon as I click a button, the styling behaves correctly, but it looks confusing at first for a user seeing the middle button correctly highlighted (checked), with the first button also highlighted, albeit with a different color.

Is there a way I can reset the hover?

Cheers

Comment: Look if there’s a class applied to the first element that is responsible for this – and if so, remove it after initializing the buttonset.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

[**DEMO IN JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/PYxz9/1/)

```
$(document).ready( function() {

  // Add the "focus" value to class attribute 
  $('ul.radio li').focusin( function() {
    $(this).addClass('focus');
  }
  );

  // Remove the "focus" value to class attribute 
  $('ul.radio li').focusout( function() {
    $(this).removeClass('focus');
  }
  );
}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys

I ended up binding to the open a focus on the text field following the buttonset.

```
open: function(){ $("#myTextField").focus(); }
```

It removes the focus from the button set, making the hover highlighting go away.